# Properties of certain topology on $[0, 1)$

Tags: general-topology, limits

Note: $\tau_{cc}$ stands for cocountable topology.

> On the real interval $[0, 1)$, we define a topology $\tau$ by declaring that, for
> $G \subseteq [0, 1), G$ is $\tau$-open iff either $0 \not \in G$ or $[0, 1)\setminus G$ is countable.

> (i) Show that (in this space) a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ converges to a limit $l$ iff $x_n = l$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

> (ii) Decide whether or not $([0, 1), \tau)$ is homeomorphic to $(\mathbb R, \tau_{cc})$.

Answers:

(i) Since $X =[0, 1) \setminus (x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots) \cup \{l\}$ is uncountable, it follows $X$ is $\tau$-open meaning $X$ is a neighborhood of $l$. Since $x_n \to l$, we have  for any neighborhood $U(l)$, there's some $N \in \mathbb N$ s.t. $n \ge N \implies x_n \in U(l)$. Thus $x_n \in X$ and $(x_n) \not \subseteq X$ meaning $x_n = l$. In the other direction, if $x_n = l$ for all $n \ge \text{ some } N_{\in \mathbb N}$, then $x_n$ is in the neighborhood of $l$ for all suitable $n$ meaning $x_n \to l$.

(ii) Any finite set with no $0$ in it is in $\tau$, but not in $\tau_{cc}$ and so there's no homeomorphism.

Do the answers above make sense? Thanks.

Comment: is it your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (i) you need to distinguish two cases:  $l =0$ and $l \neq 0$. In the latter case we know that $\{l\}$ is open (it does not contain $0$..) and the assertion follows directly from the definition of convergence applied to the neighbourhood $\{l\}$ of the limit.

In the other case $l=0$ we can define $A= \{x_n\mid x_n \neq l\}$ and this is a countable set with $0 \notin A$ so $[0,1)\setminus A$ is an open neighbourhood of $0$ so for $n$ from some $N$ onwards, $x_n \in A$, which means by definition $x_n = l$ and we're done. Your $X$ also works I think, but I find my $A$ easier to work with.

For (ii), it's enough to observe that $(\Bbb R, \tau_{cc})$ has no isolated points while all $x \neq 0$ are isolated in $([0,1),\tau)$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why every point but $0$ is isolated in $([0, 1), \tau)?$ I think we can find some $\epsilon > 0$ room around every point of $[0, 1)$. What's different about $([0, 1), \tau)?$ Is $\tau$ somehow making the points isolated? Thanks.

Comment: @user947160 no simply because $\{x\}$ is open in $\tau$ for all those $x$.

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma, understood. One last question, is it sill ok to say $\tau_{cc}$ contains no finite sets whereas $\tau$ does making the two spaces non-homeomorphic?

Comment: @user947160 It's almost the same argument but formulated more in terms of familiar topological properties, like isolated points etc.

Comment: Just in case anyone is confused about my 1st comment. I meant to say we can always find a nonempty neighborhood $N$ around any point $x$ in $[0, 1)$ s.t. $X$ contains points other than $x$ meaning every point in $[0, 1)$ is a limit point. Distracted & absentminded :)

Comment: @user947160 in $\tau$ only $0$ is a limit point. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma, I was just trying to inch myself towards understanding why everything in $([0, 1), \tau)$ is isolated by first mentioning that there are no isolated points in the set $[0, 1)$. Also, I see I wrote $X$ to mean $N$ above. Argh.

Comment: @user947160 any nonzero point is isolated. $0$ is not though. But the cocountable topology has no isolated points at all ( on an uncountable set).